# How's functions exported by ordinal called?

Tags: c, windows, export

Most function exports the name,but some exports by ordinal,

how are those functions called?

Comment: "exports by ordinary" - please explain what you mean by that.

Comment: Exported functions that don't have a name.

Comment: @Oded: that is 'ordinal'

Comment: @AProgrammer,do you mean ordinal exports only exist in windows?

Comment: @DriverBoy, perhaps not (I wouldn't be surprised if OS/2 also had them for instance) but the whole thing will be tied to the way dynamic libraries are implemented on the OS you are using.

Comment: @AProgrammer,doesn't it exist on linux?

Comment: @DriverBoy, no. (And ISTR that modern usage on Windows is not to use them, but I could be mistaken, I don't program fro Windows).

Comment: @AProgrammer: Another example, SymbianOS (as far as 9, at least), *only* has ordinals for dll symbol tables, no names at all.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the info.  I'm not surprised.  There is a trade-off between ease of use, robustness, performance,... that would make it probable for more resource starved systems to use it.

Comment: @AProgrammer: exactly, Symbian is aggressively opposed to ease-of-use ;-)

Answer (score 5):

@AProgrammer: Your question has two answers. First of all, the linker will know which ordinal number to call into. This information is saved in the .lib file when the library is created. Otherwise, as pointed out by @c-smile, you can use GetProcAddress to find the function and call it.

```
int ordinal = xxx;
functor = (MyFunctorType) GetProcAddress(hMod, (LPCSTR) ordinal);
if (functor)
{
    functor(...);
}
```

@DriverBoy: Yes, that does mean there can be no more than 65536 exported symbols in a .DLL.

Comment: by `the linker will know which ordinal number to call into`, do you mean we can still call the function using its name as long as we include its header file and lib?

Comment: Yes, as far as we (the programmers) are concerned, we don't care about ordinal numbers. We still call with names. Only at link time (that is, after our code has been compiled to objects), these symbols will be resolved to ordinals (or not). The linker will know.

Comment: but how does the linker know if the function is only exported by ordinals?Can you explain it with a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx

> lpProcName [in] The function or
>   variable name, or the function's
>   ordinal value. If this parameter is an
>   ordinal value, it must be in the
>   low-order word; the high-order word
>   must be zero.

Comment: What does **If this parameter is an ordinal value, it must be in the low-order word; the high-order word must be zero.** mean?

Comment: Does that mean the ordinal value can't be greater than 2^16?